# How to update specific variable value in Array?

Tags: jquery

This is what i tried so far. Not getting how to update only a variable value in array

```
allVals = [];
var qty;
jQuery(".big:checked").each(function() {
    qty = parseInt(jQuery(this).parents().nextAll().children().find('input[name="quantity"]').val());
    if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery(this).val(), allVals) == -1) {
        allVals.push(jQuery(this).val() + ',' + qty + ',' + 'custcol_name_of_attendees|' + nameatt + '||custcol_email_of_attendees|' + emattendee + '||custcol_event_name|' + eventname + '|    |custcol_event_location|' + eventlocation); //not present in array
    } else {
        qty = parseInt(jQuery(this).parents().nextAll().children().find('input[name="quantity"]').val()) + 1;
        // update only qty value in allVals array
    }
});
```

I want to increase qty variable value by +1 each time it finds duplicate item in array

Comment: What's the value in `('input[name="quantity"]').val()` ?

Comment: It will give me selected checkbox quantity field value....it will be integer like 1,2,3 etc

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Okay, now I think I understand what your want. Qty is not the best name for an id. Try this:

```
allVals = [];
jQuery(".big:checked").each(function() {
    var elements = jQuery(this).parents().nextAll().children().find('input[name="quantity"]');

    jQuery(elements).each(function() {
        var qty = parseInt(this.val());
        var id = this.attr('id');

        if (qty in allVals) {
           allVals[qty] += 1;
        } else {
            allVals[qty] = 1;
        }
    });

});
```

===

Your code will never find anything in the array. What your pushing into your array is

```
jQuery(this).val() + ',' + qty + ',' + 'custcol_name_of_attendees|' + nameatt + '||custcol_email_of_attendees|' + emattendee + '||custcol_event_name|' + eventname + '|    |custcol_event_location|' + eventlocation
```

but you are only searching for this

```
jQuery(this).val()
```

I think a better solution is to give your inputs an unique id and to check for that with `id in allVals`

Also array values are never updated. Only `qty` gets updated by the value of your input field.

Comment: Thanks but i am searching for qty

Answer (score 0):

First, you  find index of value by `indexOf` :

```
var index = allVals.indexOf(jQuery(this).val());
```

Then, you only update value by `=` operator :

```
allVals[index] = qty // "qty" after update value
```